# Special 301 redirection rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm moving an old site to a new domain and I've been trying to make a proper 301 redirect in the .htaccess file to accomodate the kind of redirection rules below but I think I'm stumped.

```
new.com     --> new.com/main
www.new.com --> new.com/main

old.com     --> new.com/main
www.old.com --> new.com/main

old.com/*   --> new.com/*
www.old.com/*   --> new.com/*

sub.old.com/*   --> sub.new.com/*
```

For the first part, it seems this code works:

```
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new\.com$ [OR]
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.new\.com$
# RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/new\.com\/main" [R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^$ http://www.new.com/main [R=301,L]
```

Put simple, if the browser requests any page other than the old.com domain's homepage, I'd like it to go to new.com. If someone were to visit the new.com, they'd be redirected to the /main folder. However, I'm worried that should anyone ever explicitly visit new.com/main, they'd fall into an infinite redirect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is code needed on `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` on `new.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?new\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.com/main [R=301,L]
```

This is code needed on `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` on `old.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.com/main [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://new.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%1.new.com/main [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%1.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```